# Save Android game results in cloud storage

Tags: cloud, storage, store

I want to store player's best result somewhere outside the app (Cloud or some other WEB service). And when the player entered using Google Play Game Services get his best result.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple way to do it without having to set up and manange your own server instance etc, take a look at one of the 'backend as a Service' solutions.

Common examples:

- https://parse.com
- http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/
- http://www.kinvey.com